# Panel VAR / Panel VECM

Tags: panel-data, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

I have an unbalanced panel with N=800 and T=72 (quarterly frequency). After conducting some unit root tests, all reject the null that all panels are not stationary (the alternative is that at least one panel is stationary). Further, I find that there is also cointegration between my two variables of interest. As far as I know, there is no buit-in functions in the main packages (Stata, R, Eviews or Matlab) to deal with this issue and apply a panel VECM, rather than a panel VAR. I have found some user-written programs in Stata (-xtpmg- and -xtdcce2-) in which one can apply an error correction model. However, I'm interested in impulse response functions rather than in estimations per se.
Does anybody know how to deal with this issue?